# VBA to assign a cell as an array formula

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have a sheet called "Total" that I have to duplicate which contains an array formula.  When I create a copy and rename it, the array formula is no longer entered as an array.

when I record a macro its looks like the following.

```
Range("B55").Select
    Selection.FormulaArray = _
        "=IF(R1C1=""Total"",INDEX('[All_File.xlsm]Sheet1'!R4C5:R8C5,MATCH(R[-53]C,'[All_File.xlsm]Sheet1'!R4C2:R8C2,0)),INDEX('[All_File.xlsm]Sheet1'!R5,MATCH(R1C1&""Groups"",'[All_File.xlsm]Sheet1'!R4&'[All_File.xlsm]Sheet1'!R3,0)))"
```

This issue with this is that it is referencing the file in the formula.  The file reference can change so this recorded macro would not work.

Is there a way to select a cell and have it be entered as an array?

For example:

```
 Range("B55").Select
        Selection.FormulaArray
```

the cell is being selected and entered as an array.  Again my issue with the recorded macro is that it is storing the file name, which will change, so the recorded macro cant be used again.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the file name before adding the formula:

```
Dim f As String, myFile

f = "=IF(R1C1=""Total"",INDEX('[{file}]Sheet1'!R4C5:R8C5,MATCH(R[-53]C," & _ 
    "'[{file}]Sheet1'!R4C2:R8C2,0)),INDEX('[{file}]Sheet1'!R5," & _ 
    "MATCH(R1C1&""Groups"",'[{file}]Sheet1'!R4&'[{file}]Sheet1'!R3,0)))"

myFile = 'get your filename here...    

Range("B55").FormulaArray = Replace(f, "{file}", theFilename)
```